# Error While integrating Dynamic Jasper with Struts2

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

This the error i get while integrating struts 2 and dynamic jasper

Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'dynamicjasper' mapped with name 'success'

it caused because of my report.xml where i have defined the result type dynamic-jasper

```
<package name="report" extends="struts-default,jasperreports-default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"></result-type>
            <result-type name="dynamic-jasper" class="ar.com.fdvs.dj.struts2.DJStruts2Result"/>
        </result-types>

<action name="ShowReport" class="hris.report.action.GetReportAction">
              <result name="success" type="dynamic-jasper">
                <param name="dynamicReport">dr</param>
                <param name="layoutManager">classic</param>
                <param name="format">PDF</param>
            </result>
        </action>
   </package>
```

Comment: i tried removing the extends jasperreports-default but still the same error

Comment: have you added the DynamicJasper Struts2 plugin jar? get it from here: http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/ar/com/fdvs/DynamicJasper-Struts2/1.3/